# При обращении к базе данных из Java servlet'а используя hibernate возникает ошибка. Если пользоваться стандартным JDBC, то проблем не возникает

Tags: java, hibernate, servlet, jdbc

Стэктрэйс ошибки:

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:223)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:120)
        org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:255)
    org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:34)
    org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit>(JavaReflectionManager.java:73)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.generateDefaultReflectionManager(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:741)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:715)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:654)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    net.chemodurov.dao.HibernateUserDAOImpl.<init>(HibernateUserDAOImpl.java:17)
    net.chemodurov.controller.Validate.check(Validate.java:18)
    net.chemodurov.servlet.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:44)
    net.chemodurov.servlet.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:20)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1907)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1750)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:223)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:120)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:255)
    org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:34)
    org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit>(JavaReflectionManager.java:73)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.generateDefaultReflectionManager(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:741)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:715)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:654)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    net.chemodurov.dao.HibernateUserDAOImpl.<init>(HibernateUserDAOImpl.java:17)
    net.chemodurov.controller.Validate.check(Validate.java:18)
    net.chemodurov.servlet.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:44)
    net.chemodurov.servlet.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:20)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Код сервлета:

```
package net.chemodurov.servlet;

import net.chemodurov.controller.Validate;
import net.chemodurov.dao.HibernateUserDAOImpl;
import net.chemodurov.dao.UserDAO;
import net.chemodurov.model.User;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name = "LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getParameter("password")
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String username = request.getParameter("name");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    if (Validate.check(username, password)) {
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("accessGranted");
        rs.forward(request, response);
    }
    else {
        out.println("Access denied!");
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        rs.include(request, response);
    }
}
```

}

Код валидатора:
    package net.chemodurov.controller;

```
import net.chemodurov.dao.HibernateUserDAOImpl;
import net.chemodurov.dao.UserDAO;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Validate {
        public static boolean check(String name, String password) {
        return new HibernateUserDAOImpl().validate(name, password);
    }
//    public static boolean check(String name, String password) {
//        boolean status = false;
//        try {
//            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
//            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
//                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ProductManufacturerSystem", "user",     "password");
//
//            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
//                    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND     password=?");
//            ps.setString(1, name);
//            ps.setString(2, password);
//
//            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
//            status = rs.next();
//
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            System.out.println(e);
//        }
//        return status;
//    }
```

Код HibernateUserDAOImpl:
    package net.chemodurov.dao;

```
import net.chemodurov.model.User;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class HibernateUserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    private Session session;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public HibernateUserDAOImpl() {
        sessionFactory = new     Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(String username, String password) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from User where     name=:username and password=:password");
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        query.setParameter("password", password);
        boolean result = !query.list().isEmpty();
        session.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(User entity) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(entity);
        session.close();
    }

    @Override
    public User getById(Long id) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        User user = session.get(User.class, id);
        session.close();
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User entity) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(entity);
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User user = session.get(User.class, id);
        session.delete(user);
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<User> getAll() {
        Set<User> users;
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.createQuery("FROM User").list();
        users = new HashSet<User>(session.createQuery("FROM User").list());
        session.close();
        return users;
    }
}
```

Это мой учебный проект, хочу понять как работают сервлеты.
UPD:
POM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>ProductManufacturerSystem</groupId>
<artifactId>ProductManufacturerSystem</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <!--mysql-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--hibernate-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--servlet-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--apache common codec for hashing password-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <finalName>ProductManufacturerSystem</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>8080</port>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder Вам что-то это говорит?

Comment: Ну не особо, при попытке загуглить я так понял что Java не может найти класс какого-то логгера, но я вообще не использую логирования и не подключал ничего похожего через зависимости в Maven

Comment: [Судя по всему](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20177908/3212712) вам надо добавить зависимость либы логгера. Покажите скрипт сборки где у вас зависимости указаны

Comment: Вот это вам, наверное, надо добавить, т.к. `hibernate` использует эту либу, а без него её у вас нет вот и падение: `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Юрий, добавил. Спасибо за совет, сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решена благодаря ценной подсказке уважаемого [ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/) Спасибо!

Проблема заключалась в следующем:

1. не хватало зависимости в pom.xml библиотеки SLF4J (Simple Logging Facade for Java) — библиотека для протоколирования, ставящая своей целью предоставить максимально простой, но при этом мощный фасад для различных систем протоколирования на Java.
2. после того как я добавил эту библиотеку, в моём коде образовался конфликт между зависимостями hibernate-core и hibernate-annotations. Решил это, убрав зависимости hibernate-annotations.

Надеюсь, что этот ответ поможет такому же новичку как и я.